# RESTful api design for a conversion function

Tags: http, rest

I am building a RESTful api for a library using flask .This library basicaly has a bunch of functions which takes in input in unicode strings and and does spellchecking/translation/transliteration etc .

As I see it the functions are the resources and and I am creating a conversion when I make request and seems that I should make a POST only api.

Also since I am not storing anything should I be using GET ?

Are there any other approaches for non CRUD Rest Api ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have much of a choice:

- your resource expects text to process
- the RESTful way of submitting text is through an entity body
- `GET` requests do not support entity bodies

It's really a choice between `POST` and `PUT`, and that one is clear cut: you're not creating a resource, so it can't be `PUT`.

Answer (score 1):

The function/method cannot be a resource because it means that you are making RPC (remote procedure call). Resource is just a source of an information (a noun, e.g. user, thing, etc.). On the other side RPC is about calling methods/functions (a verb, e.g. createUser(), doSomething()).

Resource in REST is just a source of an information which also provides uniform interface (uniform across all resources you are providing, mostly just CRUD operations).

So you have two options:

- rethink the library you are using, find proper nouns and publish them as resources accessible via uniform interface
- drop RESTful API requirement and easily implement RPC gateway to the library